# Getting dropdown value then inserting it to textbox inside a table, but doesn't change the second row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

[image]
I'm trying to get the value of a dropdown then inserting it to my textboxes then after that it will save to database. The data is coming from the database. The problem is after I select data from the dropdown then click the insert button; only one textbox has changed. The other row is not changing. And when I click on insert button of the 2nd row, it changes the 1st row textbox.

**javascript**

```
function copyValue(id) {
    var dropboxvalue = document.getElementById('mydropbox').value;
    document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = dropboxvalue;
}
```

**home.php**

```
      <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="insert"  onclick="copyValue(<?php echo $r['so_id'] ?>)" class="btn btn-success" value="Insert" /></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="dar_numberr" id="mytextbox" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Delivery Date" value="<?php echo $r['dar_numberr'] ?>"></textarea></td>
```

**dropdown**

```
<?php
            $databaseHost = "localhost"; 
            $databaseUser = "root";
            $databasePassword = "";
            $databaseName = "csl_otd";

            $con=mysql_connect($databaseHost ,$databaseUser ,$databasePassword )or die ('Connection Error');
            mysql_select_db("csl_otd",$con) or die ('Database Error');
         ?>
             <select name="dar_number" id="mydropbox" class="form-control"> 
             <option value=""> -----------Available DAR Number----------- </option> 
         <?php
            $dd_res=mysql_query("Select DISTINCT dar_number from dar");
            while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
            { 
               echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
            }
         ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: Can you add your exact problem to the question? Is there an error you are getting or something similar you need help with? Also see the help center for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sirence is this okay now?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it helps a lot. Could it be that you are using the same Id (mytextbox) for both your input fields? Ids have to be unique across all elements one one page.

Comment: Also, if you click the insert button in a row, do you want to update only the input in that row, or all inputs?

Comment: Only in that row @Sirence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are only targeting a specific id in your javascript, and that you might be using the same id for multiple inputs in different rows. Ids have to be unique.

So instead, try this approach:

```js
//change only the input in the same row by click on button
function copyValue(event) {
    var dropboxvalue = document.getElementById('mydropbox').value;
    event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = dropboxvalue;
  }

//change all inputs by click on button
  function updateAllRows() {
    var dropboxvalue = document.getElementById('mydropbox').value;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('mytextbox');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      inputs[i].value = dropboxvalue;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!-- example dropdown -->
<select id="mydropbox">
  <option>myOption</option>
  <option>myOtherOption</option>
</select>

<!-- example if you want to update all rows at once -->
<button onclick="updateAllRows()">
  Update all rows
</button>

<!-- example table -->
<table>

  <tr>
    <!-- here, add the event to your function call to access the exact button that was clicked -->
    <td><input type="submit" name="insert" onclick="copyValue(event)" class="btn btn-success" value="Insert" /></td>

    <!-- here, change id to class - if you use it somewhere, css or something similar, use '.' instead of '#' -->
    <td><input class="form-control mytextbox" name="dar_numberr" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Delivery Date" value="myNumber" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- second row -->
    <td><input type="submit" name="insert" onclick="copyValue(event)" class="btn btn-success" value="Insert" /></td>
    <td><input class="form-control mytextbox" name="dar_numberr" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Delivery Date" value="myNumber" /></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ba91jpxf/

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. One last thing, how can I save this to the database? @Sincere. Thank you in advance as well.

Comment: @Hahatdog To save all changes into your database, you can add a save button for your whole database that sends the new data to a php post action via submit, in which you run an insert / update sql. If you want to save instantly on pressing any insert button, you can add an ajax call to your `copyValue` function, that sends the changed data to a rest controller, which in turns saves it to the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961488/how-can-i-update-my-data-in-the-table-to-database-with-the-use-of-javascipt?noredirect=1#comment92830316_52961488